# How do I move or replace a file or folder in Visual Basic 2010?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

When debugging I get the following error.

> Unhandled exception has occurred
>
> Could not complete operation since a file already exists in this path "C:\32bit\abc.dll"

How can I fix this issue?

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ReactorButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ReactorButton1.Click
        If ReactorComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Some Program" Then
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
                ("http://somesite/test/abc.dll", _
                "C:\32bit\abc.dll", True, 500)
                System.IO.File.Move("C:\32bit\abc.dll" "C:\Program Files\Some Program\abc.dll")

            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
                ("http://www.somerandomsite/test1/abcd _
                "C:\64bit\abcd.dll", True, 500)
                System.IO.File.Move("C:\64bit\abcd.dll… "C:\Program File (x86)\Some Other Program\abcd.dll")
        End If
    End Sub
```

I also have tried

```
Try
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.IO.File.Delete("C:\32bit\abc.dll")
    End Try
    Try

    Catch ex As Exception
        My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile _
            ("http://somesite.com/folder/32bit/abc.dll", _
            "C:\32bit\abc.dll", True, 500)
    End Try
    System.IO.File.Copy("C:\32bit\abc.dll", "C:\Program Files (x86)\A Program\Sub Folder\abc.dll")
```

But I still get the same unhandled exception error.

Comment: Your Move methods look strange.  Shouldn't there be a comma between the two file names?  (i. e.  System.IO.File.Move("C:\32bit\abc.dll" **,** "C:\Program Files\Some Program\abc.dll")

Answer (score 0):

It is because the file exists. You need to delete it before download (your version delete is in the wrong place, should be in Try, not Catch)

Check *[My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)*. You can have a overwrite flag in `DownloadFile`:

> *overwrite* is set to False and the destination file already exists (IOException).

Answer (score 0):

Review *[My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)* (MSDN).

FYI, it is bad coding practice to run code in the `catch` block. `catch` blocks are usually meant to truly catch the execption.

The issue you might be running into is that you are trying to move the file before it is completely downloaded and therefore you are getting the exception.